# Pandas Assign, Lambda, List Comprehension Question

Tags: pandas, lambda, list-comprehension, assign

I receive data as a list of dicts in a single column. Each list can be a different length. Sample data looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [[{'value': 1}, {'value': 2}, {'value': 3}]],
        [[{'value': 4}, {'value': 5}]]
    ],
    columns=['data'],
)

df
                                          data
0   [{'value': 1}, {'value': 2}, {'value': 3}]
1   [{'value': 4}, {'value': 5}]
```

I want to create a new column `min_val` which contains the minimum value for each row. I'm trying this:

```
df.assign(min_val=lambda row: min(val['value'] for val in row.data))
```

But I get the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

A very similar lambda/comprehension combination works in Dask Bag but not in raw Pandas, which is very confusing.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with a callable argument works on the entire dataframe, not on rows, so you need to then [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) your function to the `data` series:

```py
df = df.assign(min_val=df.data.apply(lambda r:min(v['value'] for v in r)))
```

Output:

```
                                         data  min_val
0  [{'value': 1}, {'value': 2}, {'value': 3}]        1
1                [{'value': 4}, {'value': 5}]        4
```

Comment: Thank you all, all very helpful. Having read the assign() documentation for a callable it now makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['min_val'] = df['data'].apply(lambda x: min(item['value'] for item in x))
```

Comment: That works, thanks. I'm still a bit confused why my very similar code doesn't work with .assign(...) to create a new column. I'm trying to chain my Pandas operations for clarity/readability.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your *listcomp* is iterating through the column `"data"` (*as a whole*) of the new DataFrame returned by [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and not through the dicts of each *list/row*.

```
# 1st iteration
# `val` is equal to [{'value': 1}, {'value': 2}, {'value': 3}]
# thus, val["value"] (list[str]) will trigger the TypeError

# 2nd iteration
# `val` would be equal to [{'value': 4}, {'value': 5}]]
```

To fix that, an option would be to add another loop, so you can reach the *keys/values* of each dict :

```
out = df.assign(min_val= [min(k["value"] for k in d) for d in df["data"]])

# 167 µs ± 4.34 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

                                         data  min_val
0  [{'value': 1}, {'value': 2}, {'value': 3}]        1
1                [{'value': 4}, {'value': 5}]        4
```

Comment: A lovely explanation. Thank you.